# How to prove that the triangle is isosceles triangle if the median is equal?

Tags: geometry

How to prove that the triangle is isosceles triangle if the median of triangle is equal?

Comment: This question probably belongs in [math.se].

Comment: See Theorem$\#2$  of http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/word/geometry/Medians-in-an-isosceles-triangle.lesson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For triangle $ABC$, let $AD$ and $BE$ be the medians whose lengths are equal. From cosine law, we have the following identities:
$$4AD^2 = 2AB^2 + 2AC^2-BC^2$$
$$4BE^2 = 2BC^2 + 2BA^2-AC^2$$
Since $AD = BE$, we have
$$2AB^2 + 2AC^2-BC^2 = 2BC^2 + 2BA^2-AC^2 \implies AC^2 = BC^2 \implies AC = BC$$